# Updating server with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I have a change I want on my server I do this:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

This is pretty quick but does involve site going down briefly.  Is there a way to do it with a smaller amount of downtime or is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose down is not required. After the pull, you can directly do docker-compose up. It will only restart the containers for which there is a new version of the image after the docker pull. It will not impact the containers whose image stays the same. This setup works fine for me.